# Express/nginx/serve-favicon site of Raspberry Pi not serving favicon

Tags: html, node.js, express, nginx, raspberry-pi

## Missing Favicon

### Express/nginx/serve-favicon

I went through this [fireship tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/host-website-raspberry-pi/) to setup my own http server on an rPi, and thought it would be cool to add a favicon, but so far nothing works. I am a novice with nginx/express so have probably made some elementary mistake.

- I have nginx serving a static site running with node and express.
- I have the `serve-favicon` dependency installed.
- I have tested the file with 'file favicon.ico' and it is fine.
- favicon.ico is in the root directory:

[image: file_structure]

#### Express - server.js

```js
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
app.listen(5000, () => console.log('http://localhost:5000/'))

const favicon = require('serve-favicon')
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname,'favicon.ico')));
```

#### HTML (tried with/without)

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

#### nginx - default

```json
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                try_files $uri =204;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

}
```

After adding `location = /favicon.ico {...}` to the nginx default file, I no longer get a 404, but the file is still not being served.

- Shouldn't the file be served if there is a location for / anyway?
- Is proxy_pass adding a complication I don't know how to resovlve.

edit:

Tried below suggestion but still no joy.

```json
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                 alias /var/www/html/favicon.ico;
        }

}
```

edit 2:

I am able to see favicon.ico **locally** with nginx and server.js in the following setup:

##### /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
        location = /favicon.ico {
                  alias /var/www/html/favicon.ico;
        }
```

##### server.js

```
app.use("/favicon.ico", express.static("./favicon.ico"));
```

the icon is served when visiting `http://localhost:5000` but not when visiting the network address, and not when visiting the external site address

edit 3:

I am not sure how, but it has spontaneously started working using express.

- I have the file being served with express
- I have the file being given a proxy_pass with nginx

  - It seems any route must be explicitly laid out like this to work
- the link to the file referenced in the HTML doesn't seem to be neccessary

Comment: To simplify this you could just get rid of nginx as all it does basically proxies all requests to express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need extra dependencies for this.

### First approach:

Serve using express. (It is not recommended to serve static files using Node/Express. But it is okay for tiny projects)

- favicon.ico is in the root directory:

Express - server.js:

```
app.use("/favicon.ico", express.static("./favicon.ico"));
```

nginx - default:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico;
}
```

### Second approach:

Serve using Nginx.

- favicon.ico is in the `/var/www/html/` directory:

nginx - default:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    alias /var/www/html/favicon.ico;
}
```

Comment: I've tried both methods and have been met with failure. I have tried saving changes to the default file and then running `sudo service nginx restart` to apply the changes.

Comment: Are you sure Nginx applies the file you are working on? And no syntax error? (to check that `sudo nginx -t`)

Comment: that is a really cool tip! yup the syntax reports as fine... wait it is a report from /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and not /etc/nginx/sites-available/default... ahh I understand it pools all that together in nginx.conf?

Comment: One thing I was wondering is which is a correct: `location = /favicon.ico` or `location /favicon.ico`, as the documentation suggests no `=` but I think I tried both with no success.

Comment: is a copy of `favicon.ico` meant to be in `/var/www/html/` literrally?

Comment: 1) Yes, you are right, the main file is `nginx.conf` (usually named like that). And it pools all (using `include`) other conf files; 

2) The `=` means an exact match; NGINX's fastest processing;

3) If you go with the second approach, favicon.ico must be accessible to Nginx. The path doesn't have to be exactly the same. Just let Nginx know the correct path.